# How to read a fortran outputted matrix with python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a weird matrix output that is restricted by width as follows, so only four columns are printed at a time. I know the number of rows and columns, is there a way to read this into numpy array with python?

OVERLAP MATRIX

```
                            1            2            3            4
 1    1  He    2s        1.000000    -0.021832     0.000000     0.000000
 2    1  He    3s       -0.021832     1.000006     0.000000     0.000000
 3    1  He    3py       0.000000     0.000000     0.999992     0.000000
 4    1  He    3pz       0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.999992
 5    1  He    3px       0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000

 6    2  He    2s        0.018525    -0.049141     0.000000    -0.032037
 7    2  He    3s       -0.049141     0.116451     0.000000     0.039779
 8    2  He    3py       0.000000     0.000000     0.007411     0.000000
 9    2  He    3pz       0.032037    -0.039779     0.000000     0.005145
10    2  He    3px       0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000

                            5            6            7            8
 1    1  He    2s        0.000000     0.018525    -0.049141     0.000000
 2    1  He    3s        0.000000    -0.049141     0.116451     0.000000
 3    1  He    3py       0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.007411
 4    1  He    3pz       0.000000    -0.032037     0.039779     0.000000
 5    1  He    3px       0.999992     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000

 6    2  He    2s        0.000000     1.000000    -0.021832     0.000000
 7    2  He    3s        0.000000    -0.021832     1.000006     0.000000
 8    2  He    3py       0.000000     0.000000     0.000000     0.999992
 9    2  He    3pz       0.000000    -0.000000    -0.000000     0.000000
10    2  He    3px       0.007411     0.000000     0.000000     0.000000

                            9           10
 1    1  He    2s        0.032037     0.000000
 2    1  He    3s       -0.039779     0.000000
 3    1  He    3py       0.000000     0.000000
 4    1  He    3pz       0.005145     0.000000
 5    1  He    3px       0.000000     0.007411

 6    2  He    2s       -0.000000     0.000000
 7    2  He    3s       -0.000000     0.000000
 8    2  He    3py       0.000000     0.000000
 9    2  He    3pz       0.999992     0.000000
10    2  He    3px       0.000000     0.999992
```

Comment: Read the 3 blocks with individual `genfromtxt` calls, and join the results.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify your question. Regarding the input file: Does it look exactly as you have shown here, with the four fields before the numbered columns, and with the numbers of the columns  above the columns in a separate line? Do you have any restrictions on the kind of programming? Python has excellent file and string handling, so of course it can do what you ask, but are you asking for shortcuts?

Comment: thanks a lot @hpaulj for the idea, I can use something like
np.genfromtxt('filename',skip_header=5,max_rows=10,usecols = (4,5,6,7),delimiter='   ',autostrip=True)

Comment: @RoryDaulton it may vary depending on how many items i am going to print, this is just a sample file but in essence it prints only 4 columns and goes to the next line to print the next four.

Comment: You can read the whole thing by the `usecols` as you mentioned, then reshape it